# vb6 - Using a structure as a class property type

Tags: vb.net, vb6

I'm trying to complete a project and am finding trouble when it comes to class property types.

Can I declare a class property as a Coord?

```
Public Property Coord() As Coord
    Get
        Return coordinate
    End Get
    Set(ByVal Value As Coord)
        coordinate.x = Value.x
        coordinate.y = Value.y
    End Set
End Property

Public Structure Coord
    Public x As Integer
    Public y As Integer
End Structure
```

I get this error on compilation:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.MissingMemberException' occurred in Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll
>   Overload resolution failed because no accessible 'Coord' accepts this number of arguments.

Set with this:

```
Current.Coord(NewCoord)
```

Where NewCoord is of type Coord

Comment: You probably want `Current.Coord = NewCoord`.  This doesn't look like VB6.

Comment: Really unclear what this has to do with VB6. Are you trying to convert over some VB6 code to .NET or something?

Comment: If this is VB6 and not .net then replace `Structure` with `Type`

Comment: Can you use the existing Point structure in Drawing or Windows? Either is fleshed out a bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some of your problem might stem from using the word "Coord" for your class name and your structure name. I suspect you need to turn `Option Strict` on, `Option Explicit` on, and `Option Infer` off in your project properties compile options.

As @Mary said in the comments above, if your Coord class is purely to store an x,y coordinate, you would be much better looking at the Point structure. If however you need some other functionality in your Coord classs, I would still consider ditching your Coord structure and use the point structure. Consider this

```
Private Class CoordClass
    Private coordinate As New Point
    Public Property Coord() As Point
        Get
            Return coordinate
        End Get
        Set(value As Point)
            coordinate = value
        End Set
    End Property
End Class
```

and then you can use it like this

```
Dim aCoordinate As New Point
aCoordinate.x = 3
aCoordinate.y = 8

coordInstance.Coord = aCoordinate
```

or

```
coordInstance.Coord = New Point(4, 5)
```

Much simpler than the alternative of renaming your `Coord` strutcure so that it isnt confused with you `Coord` class and having to assign values using something like

```
Dim aCoordinate As New Coord.structCoord
aCoordinate.x = 3
aCoordinate.y = 8
```

or

```
coordInstance.Coord = new coord.structCoord with {.x=4 , .y=5}
```

**And most importantly**

The point structure is built into .net and easier to maintain in 6 months time, or by other programmers.